# Appearance -> Menu editor completely unresponsive

Tags: menus

As  you can see in the image below, I am unable to edit any of my menus (French & English). When login in the dashboard of my website today, the menu editor in appearance was completely unresponsive. Aside from editing some page titles, nothing else was done to the site. In addition to the structure not displaying, none of the links are actually working. Clicking on the drop down arrows or links just does not do anything.

Would anyone be able to help me solve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: The responsive topic is not relevant. I think you have an error on javascript. Check the console (F12 -> Tab Console) of your browser for a error hint.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a conflict with your plugins. That's why, you are seeing this blank page. Follow these steps to solve the issue:

1. Purge the cache content of your cache plugin or server cache.
2. Deactivate all the plugins. Then reactivate them one by one. In this
   way, you can find the defective one, which you have to replace with
   an alternative option.
3. Clear your browser history. Then head to **Appearance > Menu**. You
   will find that the issue has been fixed.